# Método CreateControl() para objetos OLE falla

Tags: c++

tengo un problema con mi código, estoy intentando crear una aplicación de WebBrowser dentro de una ventana inmersa en un TabControl, es decir, el Browser solo se mostrará en uno de los Tabs, sin embargo, y a pesar de que no me marca errores, el método CreateControl que utilizo para mi objeto de la clase CWnd, parece no fallar, pero tampoco asigna los parámetros al objeto como debería de hacerlo.

A continuación dejo el código de mi método para crear la ventana del Browser

```
BOOL SimpleBrowser::Create(DWORD dwStyle, const RECT& rect, CWnd* pParentWnd, UINT nID)
{
    BOOL results = TRUE;
   _Browser = NULL;

    // create this window
    CWnd *window = this;
    results = window->Create(AfxRegisterWndClass(CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW), NULL, dwStyle, rect, pParentWnd, nID);

    if (!results) return FALSE;

    // create browser control window as child of this window; 
    // this window sinks events from control
    //CRect browser_window_rect(0, 0, (rect.right - rect.left), (rect.bottom - rect.top));
    CRect       browser_window_rect;
    this->GetWindowRect(&browser_window_rect);
```

Aquí está la línea donde sospecho que se encuentra el problema

```
results = _BrowserWindow.CreateControl(CLSID_WebBrowser, NULL, dwStyle, browser_window_rect, this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST);

    if (!results) 
    {
        DestroyWindow();
        return FALSE;
    }

    // get control interfaces
    LPUNKNOWN unknown = _BrowserWindow.GetControlUnknown();
    HRESULT hr = unknown->QueryInterface(IID_IWebBrowser2, (void **)&_Browser);

    if (!SUCCEEDED(hr)) 
    {
        _BrowserWindow.DestroyWindow();
        DestroyWindow();
        return FALSE;
    }

    // navigate to initial blank page
    if (_Browser != NULL)
    {
        Navigate(_T("about:blank"));
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

En la declaración de CWinApp::InitInstance() ya tengo definido AfxEnableControlContainer(); pero no entiendo porqué en la asignación de result para _BrowserWindow me regresa un valor de FALSE y no genera el control correspondiente.

Agradezco su ayuda.